# Missing argument for parameter #1 in function call

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble returning a variable from a `func`:

```
class SearchVC: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    var test: NSString = SearchVC.dd()!

    func dd() -> NSString {
        let testing: NSString = "d"
        return testing
    }
}
```

`Error: missing argument for parameter #1 in call`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dd()` seems to be a class method so you should prepend `class` to the method signature.

```
class func dd() -> NSString {
    ...
}
```

Besides, please note that `;` at the end of each expression/assignment is totally optional so you can simply skip it.

Since your method doesn't return an `implicitly unwrapped optional`, you should also delete `!` too.

```
var test: NSString =  SearchVC.dd()
```

Comment: Or create an instance of `SearchVC` when calling `dd` by doing `var test:NSString = SearchVC().dd()!;`